# Can istio provide the caller identity to the application when using mTLS

Tags: istio

In our istio cluster we are using mTLS for authentication/authorization.
This is nice but it would be great to pass on this identification to the target application so it could provide fine grained authorization.

Could this information be set in a header? For example the service name or even the full client cert.

I looked here but did not see anything: [Istio Authentication](https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/security/#authentication)

Any pointers about how to do this would be great.
I assume this is done in the [Envoy Proxy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_conn_man/headers#x-forwarded-client-cert) Any idea how I can configure this?

p.s. I'm an application developer but I will ask our devops guys to interpret for me :-)